# Mocha test output fonts missing?

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, unicode, console, mocha.js

I am running my Mocha unit tests like below (with output)

```
[jiewmeng@JM Tickle]$ cake test-ui
path.existsSync is now called `fs.existsSync`.


  hello
    ��� should pass 
    ��� should pass 2 

  Home page
    ��� should have a title of Express (72ms)


  ��� 3 tests complete (77ms)
```

As you can see (hopefully), I am having "?" instead of ticks/crosses I'd expect? I think I am missing some fonts? Which are they? I am on Arch Linux

**UPDATE**

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Font is DejaVu Sans Mono Book

Comment: Which terminal are you using and do you have utf8 support enabled?

Comment: @travis, its the XFCE terminal. How do I check UTF8 support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A likely issue is that your encoding is not utf-8.

Try running `locale` in your terminal. If you support utf-8, you should see something similar to:

```
[ ~ ]
➜ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
[ ~ ]
➜
```

(I'm on OSX so my output may have more or less variables; the important thing to note is the `en_US.UTF-8` values).

If not, you may want to try uncommenting (or adding) a line in your config:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Depending on your system, the appropriate config file might be one of:

- /etc/rc.conf     # <= Arch Linux
- /etc/environment
- /etc/profile.d/lang.sh

That will change the encoding for all users, but you could theoretically also just make the change for your user by adding the line to one of:

- ~/.pam_environment
- ~/.profile

I may be able to provide more information knowing your system (os, version, etc).

You may also want to see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22435/how-to-fix-character-encoding-in-bash-arch-linux

Comment: Oops... totally missed the "Arch Linux" note above. Adjusting my response.

Comment: So I `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and now I see UTF-8 in the `locale` output but my fonts are still missing? Maybe the fonts are unavailable?

Comment: Are the rest of the variables utf-8 also or just LANG? (Would you paste your `locale` output?) Also what font are you using? (Can you check the terminal preferences?)

Comment: I found a few resources regarding the status of unicode support and DejaVu. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DejaVu_Sans_Mono http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/index.php?title=Current_status You may want to try switching to another font (I use Menlo; a [comparison between Menlo & DejaVu](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2009/10/the-compleat-menlovera-sans-comparison/)). See if that is helpful.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that Menlo was OSX built-in; thought I downloaded it :( Try [M+](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/M-1m), looks completely different, but I just tested it.

Answer (score 0):

To find out which encoding your terminal uses you could have a look into `/usr/share/xsessions/06xfce4.desktop` (Source: [XFCE faq](http://wiki.xfce.org/faq)).

Looking into the [mocha source](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/blob/master/lib/reporters/base.js) it seems it is not a font issue as they just set the character as an UTF-8 char itself. Also the source just indicates that whenever they set a font they use something similar to `'helvetica, arial, sans-serif'`, which could default to a font, not supporting the character, on your system. (Source: `find . -iname "*.*" -exec grep -Hn "font" {} \;` on source code - also they seem to use font: `12px monaco, monospace`; in css, but as far as I read this doesn't have anything to do with the console output.)

Try to find out which font your terminal uses or to which 'helvetica, arial, sans-serif' defaults on your system. (Probably the easiest way to check is by using css.)

FYI: The x symbol they seem to use:

```
✖
HEAVY MULTIPLICATION X
Unicode: U+2716, UTF-8: E2 9C 96
```